# Ruby On Rails - 'image_tag' with 'do' does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-4, frontend

I am trying to create my image as a block, but it's not working ... The app doesn't read the code inside the block :

```
<%= image_tag("house-toiture.jpg") do %>
    <%= puts "COME ON DUDE" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to add the following information inside :

```
<% @operation_presenter.works.each do |work| %>
     <!-- (<%= work.travaux %>) -->
    <button type="button" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<%= work.nom_travaux %>" data-content="travaux : <%= work.travaux %><br />
    Cout travaux : <%= work.cout_travaux %>€<br />
    TVA : <%= work.tva_travaux %>%"><%= work.nom_travaux %></button>
<% end %>
```

The idea is to add popover on the image.

Someone has an idea where comes from the issue ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: And what do you want inside image_tag?

Comment: I want to add information from the database, I edit my message.

Comment: Looking at method's source, it does not use the block: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Comment: The way to best do this is add data- tags that get parsed by javascript to create the popover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML `<img>` tags cannot have children, so this doesn't make sense.

To add popups, you need some JavaScript (or very nifty CSS with hidden checkboxes). If you don't want to write that yourself, use something like [Bootstrap popups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Well, world is changing and technology moves forward. Hopefully <img> tags will be able to have babies some day, same way as all other tags.